# TFS 2010 getting error TF26173 could not connect to the application tier

Tags: windows-7, tfs

We are running TFS 2010 and VS 2010. On my machine I keep getting "TF26173: Team Foundation could not connect to the application tier"

I have VS2010, TeamCompanion 4.2 and TFS Power Tools on Windows 7 x64 which connect to the server. I have found a fix for this which is to close everything down and clear the "C:\Users\ *user*\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\3.0\Cache" folder.

This then allows me to connect again, but within a few operations the error re-occurs. Whilst the machine is in the error state I can do Source control operations OK, but I can't view or change work items or amend area's and iterations.

All other users on the server have no issues, so I think it has to be a client issue. I have tried to query the web service url's in the cached files and all respond OK. My machine is on the same network as the OK users (all internal) so don't think it is a network issue.

Any other ideas on how to fix or get to the problem would be appreciated.

EDIT: I have found a full stack trace of the error

```
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.ConnectionException: TF26173: Team Foundation could not connect to the application tier. Check that you have a network connection and that the Team Foundation Server is available. If the problem persists, contact your Team Foundation Server administrator. ---> System.Net.WebException: The request failed with HTTP status 404: Not Found.
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Proxy.ClientServiceProxy.GetMetadataEx2(MetadataTableHaveEntry[] metadataHave, String& dbStamp, Boolean useMaster, Int32& locale, Int32& comparisonStyle, Int32& mode)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Proxy.WorkItemServer.GetMetadataEx2(String requestId, Boolean useMaster, MetadataTableHaveEntry[] metadataHave, String& dbStamp, IMetadataRowSets& metadata, Int32& locale, Int32& comparisonStyle, Int32& displayMode)
   at CProdStudioBackendChannel.GetMetadata(CProdStudioBackendChannel* , tagVARIANT* pvarLocale, tagVARIANT* pvarComparisonStyle, PsUserDisplayModeEnum* pDisplayMode, Boolean* pfUseSIDSecurity, Int32 fNoFire, Int32 fByPassFireOnThis, WorkItemServer clientService)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.DataStore.HandleComException(Int32 hr)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.DataStore.DatastoreClass.ConnectEx(String connectionString, String defaultCachePath, String instanceId, String userSamName, String userFriendlyName, String userSid, WorkItemServer clientService)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItemStore.InitializeInternal()
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItemStore.Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.ITfsTeamProjectCollectionObject.Initialize(TfsTeamProjectCollection teamProjectCollection)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsTeamProjectCollection.InitializeTeamFoundationObject(String fullName, Object instance)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsConnection.CreateServiceInstance(Assembly assembly, String fullName)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsConnection.GetServiceInstance(Type serviceType, Object serviceInstance)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsTeamProjectCollection.GetServiceInstance(Type serviceType, Object serviceInstance)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsConnection.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Attrice.TeamFoundation.Controllers.ServerWrapper.GetWorkItemStore()
   at Attrice.TeamFoundation.Controllers.TfsController..ctor(ServerWrapper server)
   at Attrice.TeamFoundation.Sidekicks.VisualStudio.TeamFoundationContext.ProjectContextChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.TeamFoundationServerExt.OnActiveContextChanged(ActiveContextChangedEventArgs args)
```

EDIT 2: I have submitted this issue to Microsoft as there doesn't seem to be an answer. You can view the ticket at

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/710158/vs2010-connection-to-tfs-error-tf26173

Thanks in advance

Dave

Comment: Is there anything in the Windows Event Viewer?

Comment: Dave, Sadly there is nothing in either client or server event logs for the time the issue happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reported this to Microsoft via the Connect Service (See link in the call).

We went through some diagnosis with Fiddler2 and identified that VS2010 SP1 was connecting to TFS (non-SP) fine, but something in VS would then try to connect to the web services which were added in TFS SP1.

Microsoft have acknoledged this as an issue in VS and put a fix in the next release, but in the near term upgrading the TFS 2010 to SP1 also fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I've run into this issue when the service accounts expire/lock out.  I'm not sure which service account failure causes the error, because in my case they all rotated out at the same time (SQL, SQL Analysis and Reporting, SQL Agent, Sharepoint, TFS, Project server, etc.)

In my case this is on a single server prototype stack- YMMV with farm installation, but in principal it should be the same.

Our 26173 error cleared after the following:

1) Reset all the service account domain passwords

2) Update all logon credentials to new passwords in Control Panel/services for affected accounts (Team server, Sharepoint, SQL... etc.)

3) Cycle/start all services in control panel/services

4) Launch TFS Administrator, confirm current credentials are set for the Application Tier Service Account

5) Launch IIS Manager

6) Under application pools, restart stopped TFS and Sharepoint pools.

That fixed our glitch anyway- there needs to be a reliable/direct way to manage credentials across a farm like this (out of the box).  Assuming this is the only supported method, it sucks. Hopefully someone out there can enlighten me on better ways to regularly rotate credentials used across a SharePoint/TFS/Project Server farm.  ;-)

Hope that helps your case out Dave-

--Tim

Comment: Thanks for the response, your answer was not the cause of my particular issue (I have added a brief summary of the solution I found) but could help others.